# I want to understand how generator-jhipster generate projects

Tags: jhipster

I want to understand how jhipster generator generate the code and how it works ?

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster

Answer (score 1):

JHipster is a nodejs program that uses [yeoman](https://yeoman.io) scaffolding system.